# How to make GCP VMs inventory in table format instead of JSON file?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, inventory, inventory-management

I want to make a table in GCP that contains all **VMs details**, I try to use **asset api** but it export a **JSON file** which is not readable.

I want an approach to **convert** this unreadable JSON file to a readable table,
or if there is any feature in GCP that allows us to make an **inventory table** for VMs in a **readable way**?

Comment: Why do you export the asset into a file and not info BigQuery?

Comment: how can I export it into BigQuery? @guillaume blaquiere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your [assets into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery#api_1)

In my company, we perform this export every day with a scheduled Cloud Functions. The traps is that every day, the content of the table is overridden.

So, 2 hours after the CLoud Functions scheduling, we have a BigQuery scheduled query that selects all the data of the asset inventory export and that inserts them into a partitioned table.

And we request the assets that we want into this partitioned table.

Comment: in asset inventory bigquery table, all the important data is in "resource data" field, how can I extract it? @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? How to parse it? Which parts do you want to extract?

Comment: yes how to parse it, for example I want to read the machine type and the disksize from the resource data how can I do that ? @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: The answer is not short. Can you open a new question for this?

Comment: Actually I can't, it seems like I've reached my Question limit in stackoverflow so I can't ask another question @guillaume blaquiere